# Slack Incoming Web Hooks - Send message @channel

Tags: slack-api

I am working with Slack API recently and my motive is to send a channel wide message at a certain time by calling a web hook provided by Slack Incoming Web hooks.

I created a web hook and got code from Slack as below

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hey, Its time for meeting!! <#G5CERWGRG|hep_test>", "link_names" : 1}' HOOK_URL
```

But i cannot notify all in the team by just sending @channel in the message as like we do in normal slack channel chat. If i send @channel in the curl message, it shows as text message in chat, and not as @channel link.

I even tried sending slack channel id **<#G5CERWGRG|hep_test>**, as shown in the above curl request. But the message posted isn't notifying all in the group.

Note : I want to keep my channel notification preference as it is (Notify only on mentions)

Note

Answer (score 52, accepted):

The correct syntax for sending @channel messages is `<!channel>`.

So the correct curl command for your example should read:

```
curl -X POST -H 'Content-type: application/json' --data '{"text":"Hey, Its time for meeting!! <!channel>", "link_names" : 1}' HOOK_URL
```

See also [here](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-formatting#variables) for reference in the official documentation. You can also try this out in the [message builder](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder).

Note that in order to overwrite the default channel for your webhook you need to also add the additional property `channel` with the channel name. That will however only work for webhooks created through custom integration, not for webhooks created by Slack apps.

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43804835/4379151) for an example on how to overwrite the channel name.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone else struggling to get this working, if you are using blocks, it looks like you need to have the `<!channel>` in the block content, and not in the text content.

The text key shows up in the notification and doesn't allow formatting, while the blocks do.

Answer (score 0):

The `chat.scheduleMessage` method (https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.scheduleMessage) will accomplish the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **"link_names": True**  in your payload and use @name :

```
    slack_data = {
                'text': 'Hi @user, this is for you',
                "icon_emoji": self._icon,
                "username": sender,
                "link_names": True
                }
```

Comment: doesn't work in my case, getting "invalid payload" error whenI add `"link_names": True`